# shell script sed replace

Tags: linux, sed

I have this file config.xml

```
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1">
<name>HelloWorld</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@callback.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
 <enter>PASSWORD</enter>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

I tried to do it with sed without success.

I need  to do this:

```
$./script.sh config.xml NEWPASSWORD
```

to get:

```
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1">
<name>HelloWorld</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@callback.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
 <enter>NEWPASSWORD</enter>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: There are tons of examples in google just search `sed replace string in file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using backreference:

```
sed "s/^\( *<enter>\)\([^>]*\)</\1$2</" "$1"
```

- `^\( *<enter>\)`: search for lines starting with any number of spaces followed by `<enter>`. Matching characters are captured with escaped parentheses.
- `\([^>]*\)<`: following characters up top next `<` are captured in a second group.
- `\1$2<`: in the substitution string, characters from first group are output(`\1`) followed by the second parameter value passed to the script, (`$2`, the new password value)

The command is applied to `$1`, the file passed as first parameter to the script (the file name).

To edit the file in place, use the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i "s/^\( *<enter>\)\([^>]*\)</\1$2</" "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The good result  is:

```
$cat script.sh

#!/bin/sh
file=$1
sed -i "s/^\( *<enter>\)\([^>]*\)</\1$2</" "$1"
```

Then:

```
$./script.sh config.xml NEWPASSWORD
```

Many thanks to everyone, especially to Kenavoz.